# Run CodeSys V2.3 in batch mode

Tags: plc, codesys

I'm afraid I'm not making much progress on the 3S forums. So you lot are going to get pestered now!

I'm using 3S Codesys v2.3

I'm trying to create a boot project and do sourcecode download on my build server and I'd like to avoid having any hardware plugged into it. I'm using the following command line to run Codesys:

Build.bat:

`"C:\Program Files\3S Software\CoDeSys V2.3\Codesys.exe" OptimusPlcFirmware.pro /cmd Build.cmd /batch`

Build.cmd:

`echo on`

`online sim off`

`project rebuild`

`online bootproject`

`online sim`

`online login`

`online sourcecodedownload`

`online logout`

`online sim off`

When I do this I get the windows "has encountered a problem and needs to close, with accompanying Send Error Report / Don't Send buttons"

The boot project has been created succesfully and the sourcecode all seems correct. Can anyone explain what's happening?

Thanks

Matt

Answer (score 1):

I run Twincat 2.11 here which is based on CoDeSys 2.3 but may be my idea can be useful. You cannot go Online (Login) until target (your local runtime as well) is in Running mode. Probably your local runtime is in Config mode and thus doesn't accept login and program download. Switch it to Running and try to run your script again.

Taras

Comment: I tried adding:
online login
online run
online sourcodedownload

but same problem still. Is Twincat freely available? A cursory google search didn't seem to help me

Comment: TwinCAT is a product of Beckhoff. Here is link to 30 days free trial (after that you must buy a license or uninstall and install it again)

http://www.beckhoff.com/english.asp?download/default.htm

Answer (score 0):

I've tested with CoDeSys 2.3.9.13 and I have a similar issue. It seems that the problem comes from the `online sourcecodedownload` command.

I didn't know if it is valid to download the source code in the PLC in simulation mode. It looks strange to me. In any case, even if it's not possible it shouldn't crash.

I hope it helps